# Display list of images in symfony2 twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have already uploaded several images in the following directory
*BundleVoteBundle/web/uploads/images/nominee/* 
Image name is unique.
now i want display all of the data with corresponding image using this controller

```
  public function indexAction()
{
    $nominee=  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BundleVoteBundle:Nomination')->findAll();
    if(!$nominee){
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('There is no nominee in your list');
    }  else {
        return $this->render('BundleVoteBundle:Nomination:index.html.twig',array('nominees'=>$nominee));
    }
}
```

Now my question is how can i display that images in twig using for loop.
in twig file i could display only one images using its image id.

```
   {% for nominee in nominees %}
    <p>{{nominee.name|upper}}</p>
    {{nominee.path}}

    <img src="{{asset('uploads/images/voter/52bbc07a8136e.jpeg')}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: <img src="{{asset('uploads/images/voter/52bbc07a8136e.jpeg')}}"/> its can display single photo. But i want list of photo.

Comment: Oh, dude , add this in your question.

Comment: And how do you get the image id?

Comment: {{nominee.path}} will display the image id

Comment: if {{nominee.path}} is path of your images, then why don't you set it as source of image, like <img src="{{ nominee.path }}" />. I'm not sure, but try this around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be pretty comfortable to have a method in `Nomination` entity that returns the path to an uploaded image:

```
class Nomination
{
    // ...
    protected $path; // here we hold filenames, like 52bbc07a8136e.jpeg
    //... 

    public function getPhotoUploadDir() {
        return 'uploads/images/voter';
    }

    //... 
}
```

Then in twig you should be able to use it this way:

```
{% for nominee in nominees %}
    <p>{{nominee.name|upper}}</p>

    // should return web/uploads/voter/52bbc07a8136e.jpeg #}    
    <img src="{{ asset(nominee.photoUploadDir) ~ '/' ~ nominee.path }}" />

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: according your define way give me this output : _<img src="/eVoting/web/uploads/images/voter/">_ . May be **nominee.path** not work here.

Comment: you should check your database to see if all Nominations have `path` set. Please, let us know where the problem was.